# Are macOS and iOS targets supposed to share the same entitlement file?

Tags: ios, macos, xcode8, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have a project that has a target for iOS and macOS. When I was adding the iCloud capability to the iOS project and I ran it, I received an error that my entitlements file contained invalid or not permitted entitlements. When I went to the build settings I noticed that my iOS target was using the same entitlement file as the macOS target.

Are both targets supposed to use the same entitlement file or should they each have their own?

Comment: Don't the two platforms have different sets of entitlements in general?

Comment: @zneak Thats what I thought. But whenever you turn on a capability for a specific target it creates a single entitlement file that they both access. I even used the multiplatform template in Xcode and got the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, different targets should, in principle, have different entitlements.

I had the same problem once, and unfortunately had to use different filenames for each target's entitlements file, or else Xcode would get them all mixed up.

You can set the entitlements file in each target's Build Settings.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Xcode by default creates one entitlement file, and automatically sets it in the build settings.

Comment: And you can change it in the Build Settings to allow different entitlements for each target…

Comment: That makes sense. I just tried it right now and everything seems to be working. Thanks for the help. +1